# Why does this not short circuit?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s = null;

    if(false && false || s.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {    //throws an exception
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

I was expecting after this encounters false to short circuit but it doesn't.
Why is that?  I assumed if you have a false there is NO need to proceed to the next &&.
Please help me to understand.

Comment: Wow!  4 answers submitted within a span of 3 seconds.

Comment: Add parens to help you see the correct order of evaluation.

Comment: @csmckelvey That doesn't make sense. Adding parentheses would either have zero effect or *change* the order of evaluation.

Comment: It's not to change anything, just to make him _see_ which things would be evaluated first. Looking at ((false && false) || someCondition) makes it easier to quickly see which part gets evaluated first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`&&` operator has higher precedence than the `||` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).  So, the condition is equivalent to

```
if( (false && false) || s.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {    //throws an exception
```

which is then evaluated to leave:

```
if(false || s.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {    //throws an exception
```

which doesn't short circuit.  To make it short-circuit, use parentheses:

```
if(false && (false || s.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))) {    // fine
```

Comment: You read my mind with: if(false && (false || s.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))) {      Problem was a null pointer exception was getting thrown on the s.equalsIgnoreCase because the value was null.  Your correction with the brackets fixes the problem. Thanks Sir!

Comment: Is it right then to say... whenever there are && followed by an || to always consider the && statements in parenthesis?  In my case just two boolean && together, but it could include a longer chain and just think of it all being in parens?

Comment: I've always considered an expression with `&&` and `||` together, but without parentheses, to be confusing.  But it all has to do with the fact that `&&` has greater precedence than `||`, so `a || b && c` would be evaluated the same as `a || (b && c)`.  For the sake of clarity, always include your own parentheses in this situation, to explicitly force your own order of operation.

Answer (score 2):

Because this:

```
a && b || c
```

is equivalent to this:

```
(a && b) || c
```

The lhs of the `||` is false, so `c` gets evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The and have higher precedence so it's bracketed like

```
((false && false) || s.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
```

`(false && false)` reduces to `false` which is not short-circuit by `||`.

---

It's worth remembering that `&` is sort of like `*` (`1 & 1 = 1` and `0 * 1 = 1`) and `+` is sort of like `|` hence `&` have higher precedence. In maths sometimes `+` is used as or and nothing for both `&` and `*`. Logic operations have the same precedence as binary ones so `&&` have higher then `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it short-circuit? || only short-circuits if the LH operand is true. && short-circuits if the LH operand is false. Here you have a short-circuing && and a non-short-circuiting ||.